# How Do I Link Git to Git.Path?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I download VS Code with extensions before I installed Git. After I installed Git, I looked for git.path so I could link it as the error said. But I couldn't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: The error said that the Git extensions couldn't find git.

Comment: Make sure the git executable is in your PATH. You can do this by just running `git --version` on the command line. If it gives an error then you have to add the git executable to the PATH env variable